# Read Argument in Code(Java) Passed during maven build

Tags: java, maven

I'm working on maven based project. I have a requirement which is "**Pass a argument during maven build and read it in java code & xml file to make customization in the code based on the argument value**".

Just wondering how we can achieve this?

Comment: Maven resources plugin can use and replace placeholders in resource files

Comment: Thanks @Michael, It would be great if you can share some example.

Comment: Take a look at the linked duplicate. The documentation for maven resources plugin is also good

Comment: Thanks, I was able to write resource(properties file) and read it in java code. But how can i read the value in xml file?

Comment: Why don't you do the same thing with the XML? Keep it as a resource containing a placeholder